# Multi select filter option for MySQL data using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am learning JSON and AJAX and need help on this tutorial.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
function makeTable(data){                   // create table get data from database
    var tbl_body = "";                      // table body
    $.each(data, function() {               // table data
        var tbl_row = "";
        $.each(this, function(k , v) {
            tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";    // table row
        })
        tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";
    })
    return tbl_body;
}

function getEmployeeFilterOptions(){        // get filter options value
    var opts = [];
    $checkboxes.each(function(){            // this function select when radiobutton is clicked
        if(this.checked){
            opts.push(this.value);          // get check box values
        }
    });
    return opts;
}

function updateEmployees(opts){             // update the filter value using ajax
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",                       // POST method
        url: "search.php",                  // search. page send data using json
        dataType : 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: {filterOpts: opts},
        success: function(records){
            $('#employees tbody').html(makeTable(records));
        }
    });
}

var $checkboxes = $("input:radio");         // check radio button is clicked
$checkboxes.on("change", function(){
    var opts = getEmployeeFilterOptions();  // update the database 
    updateEmployees(opts);
});
updateEmployees();
</script>
```

Here the results (from `search.php`) are showing in a table but I want all the data in a div. Please help me on this issue.

Comment: makeTable(records) function generates a table. change the html layout in the function display a div.

Comment: @Sasikumar thanks for your comment. Can you please provide me the code to display a div instead a table.

Comment: div cannot be displayed inside a table unless it is inside a td. Thats a lot of code to write.

Comment: The results are showing in the table but i want them in div. is there any way to display those results in a div? or i need to write div inside a td

Comment: you can remove table and form html layout using div, but its usless of placing div inside td and displaying the same data.

Comment: Yes, I want to remove the table and want a div to display the results. Please tell me the way to do this.